# How to fetch results in table cell using swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to fetch contact name and number in same cell but it fetches name in first cell and number in second cell i have added my entire coding here....

```
import UIKit
import AddressBook
import CoreData
class ContactViewController: UIViewController,CNContactPickerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
      var contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var mycontact:CNContactStore!
    var myContacts = [CNContact]()
    var names = [NSManagedObject]()
    var numbers = [NSManagedObject]()
    var yourcont:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }

    @IBAction func AddButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Contact",
                                      message: "Add a new contact",
                                      preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                       style: .Default,
                                       handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                                        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
                                         self.saveName(textField.text!)

                                        let sedfield = alert.textFields![1] as UITextField
                                         self.saveNum(sedfield.text!)
                                        self.FirstTableView.reloadData()
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                         style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Your Name"

        }
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (sedfield: UITextField) -> Void in
            sedfield.placeholder = "Enter your Number"

        }

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert,
                              animated: true,
                              completion: nil)
    }
    func saveName(name: String) {

        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                     insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


        person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")


        do {
            try managedContext.save()

            names.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    func saveNum(name: String) {

        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                     insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


        person.setValue(name, forKey: "number")


        do {
            try managedContext.save()

            numbers.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func LeftTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer?.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }

           func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if(section == 0) {
                return names.count
            }
                return numbers.count
    }
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContactCell") as! TableViewCell
      let personname = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.ConName.text =  personname.valueForKey("name") as? String
    let personnum = numbers[indexPath.row]
    cell.ConNumber.text = personnum.valueForKey("number") as? String

       return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == .Delete
        {
            numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
           tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")


        do {
            let results =
                try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            names = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            numbers = results as! [NSManagedObject]

            print(results)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
          override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Are you using custom TableViewCell??

Comment: yes....am using custom cell

Comment: What did you name the subclass of UITableViewCell?? And are you @IBOutlets all connected

Comment: yeah everything is perfectly connected but cant fetching in samecell

Comment: Is your subclass called TableViewCell?

Comment: Can you try to add a var name = personname.valueForKey("name") as? String and var number = personnumber.valueForKey("number") as? String and print(name,number) or assign one of ur labels.text = name + " " + number....just so we can figure out is the issue from the cell displaying the data or the data fetching of the data is the issue.

Comment: yes my csubclass called tableviewcell

Comment: fetching of the data is issue..i think because of using nsmanagedobject in indexpath.row instead of nsarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose Table View Cell on Storyboard and set Style with Subtitle

Comment: thats not a problem a i have assumed everything properly there is a problem in my coding only because i have assume two variables in class i.e var names and number so i cant parse in same cell...just you go through my codes once

Comment: do {
            let results =
                try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            names = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            numbers = results as! [NSManagedObject]

            print(results)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

Comment: name and number are equals same results

Comment: person.setValue(name, forKey: "number") check this line. I think it is problem